# Checkbox inside gridview in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am using checkbox in a gridview:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkhdr" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"  />
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:CheckBox CssClass="gridrownormal3" ID="chkChild" runat="server" />                          
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Button click for binding grid:

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     /*
      * Clear All Data in Grid By Calling Empty_GridView
      * */
      if (this.IsValid)
      {
           Empty_GridView(grdDocList_Summary);
           List<SearchEngineEO> doc = Docs;
           var query18 = (from c in doc 
                          select new { c.DocNO, c.DocType, c.Title, c.Padid,
                                         c.PublisherName, c.PublishedDate, 
                                         c.Rade }).Distinct().ToList();
           grdDocList_Summary.DataSource = query18;
           grdDocList_Summary.DataBind();
      }
}
```

I select the checkbox at run time, I want to show some details of these rows.
I use this code:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < grdDocList_Summary.Rows.Count; i++)
 {
      GridViewRow row = grdDocList_Summary.Rows[i];
      bool isChecked = ((CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkChild")).Checked;

      if(isChecked)
      {
           String str = row.Cells[1].Text;
           DocNos.Add(str);
      }
 }
```

Suppose I have 10 rows in `grdDocList_Summary`. When I select one checkbox, for all iteration of for above variable `ischecked` is true. Why does this happen?

Comment: in Click Event of a button

Comment: var query18 = (from c in doc select new { c.DocNO, c.DocType, c.Title, c.Padid, c.PublisherName, c.PublishedDate, c.Rade }).Distinct().ToList();grdDocList_Summary.DataSource = query18;
                    grdDocList_Summary.DataBind();

Comment: protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)if (this.IsValid)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43690/discussion-between-acomputert-and-bhavesh-kachhadiya)

Comment: Can you add `Button1_Click` event code here i.e. in your question?

Comment: Have got solution for this?